# Самое длинное слово

Tags: лексика

Какое самое длинное слово в русском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Однозначного ответа тут нет. Нередко у химических соединений очень длинные названия, но и можно счатать русскими словами все-таки с натяжкой. Также очень длинными могут быть сложные числительные. Например, "*дветысячипятьсотвосьмидесятисемилетний*".